# C: Segmentation Fault with strcpy

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault, malloc

i'm wondering if anyone could help me with this segmentation fault, valgrind and gdb point to a strcpy(), but I still can't find it..

```
void listusers(userstat* ptustat)
{
    FILE* fileu = openfile("user_db");
    char* str = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
    char* temp = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
    int i = 0;
    int offset = 0;
    while (fgets(str,100,fileu) != NULL)
        {   
            strcpy(temp,str);
            strcpy((*(ptustat+i)).name,strtok(temp,"#"));
            offset+=(strlen(temp)+1);
            strcpy(temp,str+offset);
            strcpy((*(ptustat+i)).contact,strtok(temp,"#"));
            offset+=(strlen(temp)+1);
            strcpy(temp,str+offset);
            strcpy((*(ptustat+i)).uname,strtok(temp,"#"));
            offset+=(strlen(temp)+1);
            strcpy(temp,str+offset);
            strtok(temp,"#");
            offset+=(strlen(temp)+1);
            strcpy(temp,str+offset);
            (*(ptustat+i)).saldo = atof(strtok(temp,"\n"));
            i++;
        }
closefile(fileu);
free(str);free(temp);
}
```

userstat definiton:

```
typedef struct userstat {
char name[50];
char contact[50];
char uname[50];
float saldo;
} userstat;
```

Also the file that it is reading has lines like this:
name#contact#username#password#money

gdb backtrace:

```
    Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__strcpy_sse2_unaligned () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcpy-sse2-unaligned.S:296
296 ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcpy-sse2-unaligned.S: Ficheiro ou directoria inexistente.
(gdb) bt
#0  __strcpy_sse2_unaligned () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcpy-sse2-unaligned.S:296
#1  0x00000000004030b2 in listusers ()
#2  0x0000000000401fee in statsmenu ()
#3  0x0000000000401c1d in menuinit ()
#4  0x0000000000400ecc in main ()
(gdb)
```

Calling of the function and allocation of the struct:

```
void statsmenu()
    {

        char x = '0';

        getchar(); 
        while (1)
            {
                prodstat db[100] = {{"",0.00,0.00,0.00}};
                prodstat *ptstat = db;
                userstat dbu[100] = {{"","","",0.00}};
                userstat *ptustat = dbu;
                listproducts(ptstat);
                listusers(ptustat);
```

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE].

Comment: And please show at least the definition of `userstat` and show how you call `listusers`, the origin of the problem ist most like there.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: Considering the incorrect or at least unusual use of `strtok()`, I'm not sure about that being the "most likely" problem.

Comment: Please show how you call `listusers` and how you declared/allocated the parameter you pass to this function.

Comment: compile your code with debugging turned on (-g option in gcc) and then gdb will tell you which line in `listusers` you're getting the problem

Answer (score 2):

I replaced the awkward `(*ptustat + i)).xxx` by the equivalent (but readable) `ptustat[i].xxx`.

Now your usage of `strtok` is wrong and awkward. Try this:

```
while (fgets(str, 100, fileu) != NULL)
{
    strcpy(temp, str);
    strcpy(ptustat[i].name, strtok(temp, "#"));
    offset += (strlen(temp) + 1);
    strcpy(temp, str + offset);
    char *p = strtok(temp, "#");

    if (p == NULL)   // p can be NULL here
    {
        printf("BUMMER\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    strcpy(ptustat[i].contact, p);
    offset += (strlen(temp) + 1);
    strcpy(temp, str + offset);
    strcpy(ptustat[i].uname, strtok(temp, "#"));
    offset += (strlen(temp) + 1);
    strcpy(temp, str + offset);
    strtok(temp, "#");
    offset += (strlen(temp) + 1);
    strcpy(temp, str + offset);
    ptustat[i].saldo = atof(strtok(temp, "\n"));
    i++;
}
```

I leave the correction of the bug as an exercise.

Furthermore (not related to your problem):

You can replace

```
char* str = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
...
free(str);
```

by

```
char str[100];
```

It's usually pointless to allocate fixed space buffers dynamically.

Comment: Thanks that was helpful, but i fixed the bug by erasing all those strtok statments and replacing by a single sscanf().